# How can I access a file in bash and compare its contents with stdout when running a program to make sure they are identical?

Tags: bash, shell, file, grep, piping

How can I to compare the output in stdout of a program with a model output in an output file? I ask because I am trying to make a grading script. Also, I am thinking of using -q grep, but am not sure how I would use it still.

Please make answer simple because I am a noob at bash.

Important edit:

I want to use this in an if statement. For example:

```
if(modle_file.txt is identical to stdout when running program); then
    echo "Great!"
else
    echo "Wrong output. You loose 1 point."
```

Edit:

The program takes an input. So for example if we do:

```
%Python3 Program.py
Enter a number: 5
The first 5 (arbitrary) things are:
2, 5, etc  (program output)

%
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your file is called `example.txt`, do

```
diff example.txt <(program with all its options)
```

The `<()` syntax takes the output of the program in parentheses and passes it to the `diff` command as if it was a text file.

**EDIT:**

If you just want to check whether the text file and the output of the program are the same or not in an `if`-clause, you can do:

```
if [ "$(diff example.txt <(program with all its options))" == "" ]; then
  echo 'the outputs are identical'
else
  echo 'the outputs differ'
fi
```

I.e. `diff` only generates output if the files differ, so an empty string as answer means the files are identical.

**EDIT 2**:

In principle you can re-direct stdin to a file, like so:

```
program < input.txt
```

Now, without further testing, I don't know whether this will work with your python script, but suppose you can put all the input the program expects into such a file, you could do

```
if [ "$(diff example.txt <(program < input.txt))" == "" ]; then
  echo 'Great!'
else
  echo 'Wrong output. You loose 1 point.'
fi
```

**EDIT 3:**:

I wrote a simple test program in python (let's call it `program.py`):

```
x = input('type a number: ')
print(x)
y = input('type another number: ')
print(y)
```

If you run it interactively in the shell with `python program.py`, and give `5` and `7` as answers, you get the following output:

```
type a number: 5
5
type another number: 7
7
```

If you create a file, say `input.txt`, which contains all the desired input,

```
5
7
```

and pipe that into your file like so:

```
python program.py < input.txt
```

you get the following output:

```
type a number: 5
type another number: 7
```

The reason for the difference is that python (and many other shell programs) treat input differently depending on whether it comes from an interactive shell, a pipe, or a redirected stdin. In this case, input is not echoed as the input comes from `input.txt`. However, if you run both your code and the student's code using `input.txt`, the two outputs should still be comparable.

**EDIT 4:**

As one of the comments states below, it is not necessary to compare the entire output of the `diff` command against an empty string ("") if you only want to know whether they differ, the return status is enough. It's best to write a small test script in `bash` (let's call it `code_checker.sh`),

```
if diff example.txt <(python program.py < input.txt) > /dev/null; then 
    echo "Great!"
else
    echo "Wrong output. You loose 1 point."
fi
```

the `>/dev/null` part in the `if`-clause re-directs the output of `diff` to a special device, effectively ignoring it. If you have a lot of output, it might be better to use `cmp` like mentioned by user1934428.

Comment: How can I then use this in an if statement? For example:
if(diff example.txt <(program) == 0); then
    echo "Great!"
else 
    echo "Wrong output -1 point"
fi

Comment: Could you give me an example of what you want to achieve?

Comment: How about if the program takes input? What do I put in the (your program goes here) part?

Comment: Do you mean a file as input? Can you write down the command that you would type without the `diff` and `if` statements around it?

Comment: I would write:
Python3 Program.py
#(then the program would ask for input)
Enter a number:  5
The first 5 somethings are:
 etc.... (program output)

Comment: I will write this neater as an edit on the original post

Comment: Ok, this adds a certain twist to the original question. If you are writing a python program to ask the students some questions, why don't you do the error checking inside the python program?

Comment: No, inside the python program, where you ask the student your questions, grab the input there and compare to the answer you expect. If the outputs are completely identical, my solution should still work, but it becomes very unpractical very quickly.

Comment: My program is grading the students programs. I need to run their program which will ask for input so I can then see if their output matches the example output. By running the students programs, their programs will ask me for input, but since I am using a script I need to just plug input.

Comment: Oh, ok. So can you create a file with the correct answers to your python script?

Comment: Yes. In my directory I have an output file where I would like to compare my output with theirs.

Comment: Don't use command substitution here; just use the exit status of `diff`: `if diff example.txt <(program < input.txt) > /dev/null; then echo "Wrong output"; else echo "Great"; fi`.

Answer (score 2):

One way to do this would be to redirect the `stdout` output to a file, like this:

```
myCommand > /folder/file.txt
```

And then run a `diff` command to compare the two files

```
diff /folder/file.txt /folder/model_output.txt
```

**Edit**: To use this on an `if` statement, you could do the following:

```
if [ -z "$(diff /folder/file.txt /folder/model_output.txt 2>&1)" ]; then echo "Great!"; else echo "Wrong output. You loose 1 point."; fi
```

If the files are equal, it will print `Great!`, otherwise it will print `Wrong output. You loose 1 point.`

Comment: If `/folder/file.txt' already exists before you run `myCommand`, the output of `myCommand` will be appended to `/folder/file.txt'. This may or may not be the intended behaviour. I would first make sure that the file really does not exist, and then use only one `>`, i.e. `myCommand > /folder/file.txt. See my answer for an alternative without creating a separate file.

Comment: Yes, I thought the same thing after posting (to use `>` instead of `>>`), and updated before you commented. Thanks anyways.

Comment: Generally speaking, you should not use `... && ... || ...` as a shortcut for an `if` statement. If the first command succeeds but the following one fails, the third one *still* executes.

Comment: @chepner thanks for this insight, I had not thought of that. I updated my post later with a proper `if` statement.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are not interested in the actual differences, but only in whether they are identical, I think `cmp` is the best choice (and faster if the files are large):

```
if cmp -s example.txt <(your program goes here)
then
  echo identical
fi
```

Note that this compares only stdout (as you requested), not stderr.

Comment: @muru: I forgot that `diff` has a `-q` option. Of course, `diff -q` should perform about the same as `cmp -s`. However, if you omit the `-q`, and the files are different, then diff **has** to go through the files until the end, while `diff -q` or `cmp -s` will stop at the first difference they find. Of course this will be noticeable only in fairly large files, and only if the first difference is not near the end of the files.

Comment: How about if the program takes input? What do I put in the (your program goes here) part?

Comment: You mean, input from stdin? In the same way as if you would invoke your program directly: input redirection. Everything between the parenthesis is a complete command, executed in a subshell. You can put in what you like.

Comment: @user1934428 `diff` *might* have a `-q` option; it isn't required by POSIX.